# How to embed google calendar in my website

Tags: reactjs, iframe, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate google calendar with my website, so the user can choose a date to insert in input in the website.
I have searched for a way of showing the calendar as an iframe window, but I didn't find one.
Can anyone please help me embed an iframe with the user's google calendar?

I want to achieve something similar to this

Comment: The calendar that you are trying to embed, is it from a Gmail or Google Workspace account?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. The calendar is from the Gmail account. I followed the instruction that are under the calendar settings. I placed the iframe code on my page and the google calendar does not show. What gives?